# How to process documents by batch in Mongo pipeline without using $skip?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Me and my team have some questions related to Mongo pipeline.

We have a pipeline used to process a large number of documents. In this pipeline, we use the `$group` stage. However, this stage has an hard-coded limit of 100MB, which is not enough for the quantity of document we have (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions).

The solution we implemented was a combination of the `$skip` and `$limit` stages at the beginning of the pipeline in order to process the documents by batch of N (where N is a number chosen so a batch of N documents weight less than 100MB).

However this solution has a performance issue, as the `$skip` stage get slower
as the number of documents to skip increases (https://arpitbhayani.me/techie/mongodb-cursor-skip-is-slow.html).

We then found this article: https://arpitbhayani.me/techie/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb.html. The second approach described there seems to be a good solution for our use case. We would like to implement this approach. However, for this to work, the documents have to be sorted by the internal Mongo ID (`_id`) at the start of the pipeline. We thought about using the `$sort` stage beforehand, but this stage also has a hard-coded 100MB limit.

What method could we use to ensure that the documents are sorted by `_id` at the start of the pipeline?

Is there maybe another solution to process the documents by batch weighting less than 100MB?